# Convert Json to dataset or list

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I wanted to convert json to a list or dataset m getting json from REST API in following format

```
    )]}'
{
"DASH/er/manifest": {
"kind": "gerritcodereview#project",
"id": "DASH%2Fer%2Fmanifest",
"state": "ACTIVE"
},
"DASH/er/projects/amc": {
"kind": "gerritcodereview#project",
"id": "DASH%2Fer%2Fprojects%2Famc",
"state": "ACTIVE"
},
"DASH/er/projects/dash-config": {
"kind": "gerritcodereview#project",
"id": "DASH%2Fer%2Fprojects%2Fdash-config",
"state": "ACTIVE"
},
"DASH/er/projects/dash-sccm-plugin": {
"kind": "gerritcodereview#project",
"id": "DASH%2Fer%2Fprojects%2Fdash-sccm-plugin",
"state": "ACTIVE"
},
"DASH/er/projects/dash-sdk": {
"kind": "gerritcodereview#project",
"id": "DASH%2Fer%2Fprojects%2Fdash-sdk",
"state": "ACTIVE"
},
"DASH/er/source/dash-client-sdk": {
"kind": "gerritcodereview#project",
"id": "DASH%2Fer%2Fsource%2Fdash-client-sdk", 
"state": "ACTIVE" 
},
"DASH/er/source/dash-configmgr-plugin": {
"kind": "gerritcodereview#project",
"id": "DASH%2Fer%2Fsource%2Fdash-configmgr-plugin",
"state": "ACTIVE"
},
"DASH/er/source/dash-manifests": {
"kind": "gerritcodereview#project",
"id": "DASH%2Fer%2Fsource%2Fdash-manifests",
"state": "ACTIVE"
 }
}
```

can anyone help me to convert this json to dataset or list, Thanks

Comment: Use JSON.NET, or be square (it doesn't rhyme, but that makes it no less useful, advice-wise).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have JSON.NET installed to your application as a NuGet package.

First create a model class with matching properties such as Kind, Id, and State.

```
var myList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<YourClass>>(jsonString);
```

This should give you an object list of the JSON string.

Additionally, the way your JSON is formatted it is going to be kind of hard since the highest level is unique every time. If you have control over the formatting of the JSON I would make it so you have a general class for all items such as Post in the below example:

```
{
"Post": {
"url": "DASH/er/manifest"
"kind": "gerritcodereview#project",
"id": "DASH%2Fer%2Fmanifest",
"state": "ACTIVE"
},
...
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for reply,  
but i can't fromat json because i am getting it from Gerrit API and format is like as above i mentioned and i need code for exact that json,,,,and code which you given i already tried that but got exception,,,

Comment: any other alternative way?? please let me know